# Swapping an enum value in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm currently very new to Swift and I was wondering if the following code can be optimized/shortened in any way:

```
enum CardOrientation {
    case Horizontal, Vertical
}

func toggleCurrentCardOrientation() {
    switch currentCardOrientation {
    case .Horizontal: currentCardOrientation = .Vertical
    case .Vertical: currentCardOrientation = .Horizontal
    }
}
```

Let's assume that `CardOrientation` will always just have these two possible values and every call to `toggleCurrentCardOrientation` should toggle between each of those.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

**Use a Bool instead (e.g. isCardOrientationHorizontal)**

Bools are extremely easy to toggle: `isCardOrientationHorizontal.toggle()`

**Add a toggle method to your enum:**

```
enum CardOrientation {
    case Horizontal, Vertical

    mutating func toggle() {
        switch self {
            case .Horizontal:
                self = .Vertical
            case .Vertical:
                self = .Horizontal
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for providing two different approaches. I was considering to use a Bool at first, but I somehow prefer to be able to use the awesome ".Vertical" syntax which makes it way more obvious what is happening.

Comment: The 2nd option makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

I'd move the toggle method to the enum itself. Then flag the method as `mutating` to bless it with the ability to update itself. And given that there are only two options, a `switch` seems like overkill. You can just use an `if/else`. But if you ever have more than two options, a `switch` makes more sense.

For example:

```
enum CardOrientation {
    case Horizontal, Vertical
    mutating func toggle() {
        if self == .Horizontal {
            self = .Vertical
        } else {
            self = .Horizontal
        }
    }
}

var currentCardOrientation: CardOrientation = .Horizontal
currentCardOrientation.toggle()
currentCardOrientation // .Vertical
currentCardOrientation.toggle()
currentCardOrientation // .Horizontal
```

Comment: I would say that a switch is preferable to an if statement in case he adds another case in the future. It is better to have the compiler as a safety net to make sure all cases are accounted for.

Comment: @drewag, generally speaking that's true, but in case of a `toggle` function, more than two makes little sense.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella, that is kind of the point. It is a safety net that he (or another programmer) doesn't add a case later, changing the whole paradigm in which the enum is used.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can define the `swap` function on the enum itself

```
enum CardOrientation {
    case Horizontal, Vertical

    func swap() -> CardOrientation {
        switch(self) {
        case Horizontal: return Vertical
        case Vertical: return Horizontal
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
func toggleCurrentCardOrientation() {
    currentCardOrientation = currentCardOrientation.swap()
}
```

As a personal stylistic note, I prefer not to mutate the instance itself, as introducing mutable state makes reasoning about the code increasingly difficult.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that an `enum` that's inherently flippable should have an associated raw value with that same trait. Since `Bool` cannot be used as a raw type (your first instinct), how about this?

```
enum CardOrientation: Int {
    case Horizontal = -1, Vertical = 1

    mutating func toggle() {
        self = CardOrientation.fromRaw(-self.toRaw())!
    }
}
```

On a side note... the reason for `Bool` not being able to be used—"Raw type 'Bool' is not convertible from any literal"—might be a bug since `true` and `false` became literals in one of the betas.